# KB-Hotfix installation error in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, hotfix

I am trying to install some KBs on AX but an error is occurring.
I checked the user's privileges and everything is OK

Log:

> === Setup logging started: 06/05/2020 17:56:03 === Running file: "C:\Users\XXX_IN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AxSetupSP\AxSetupUI.exe"
> RelatedFilesDir="C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb" AXSetup version
> number: 6.3.6000.6729 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 (64 bit)
> VM-SERV-HOMOLOG DOMAIN\xxxxxxxx Interactive: True
>
> RelatedFilesDir=C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb Property
> RelatedFilesDir set to: 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb' Property
> SetupLanguage set to: 'EN'
>
> === Loading parameters from the command line or a parameter file === Initializing log file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Dynamics AX\Dynamics
> AX Setup Logs\2020-05-06 17-56-03\DynamicsSetupLog.txt
>
> === Starting evaluation of existing installation state === Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 00. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 01. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: True Application Object Server instance 1 has been
> installed with the name 01-XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST. Evaluating
> installation state of Application Object Server instance 02. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 03. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 04. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 05. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 06. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 07. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 08. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 09. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 10. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 11. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 12. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 13. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 14. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 15. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 16. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 17. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 18. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 19. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 20. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 21. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 22. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 23. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 24. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 25. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 26. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 27. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 28. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 29. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 30. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 31. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 32. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 33. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 34. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 35. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 36. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 37. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 38. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 39. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 40. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 41. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 42. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 43. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 44. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 45. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 46. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 47. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 48. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 49. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 50. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 51. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 52. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 53. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 54. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 55. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 56. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 57. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 58. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 59. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 60. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 61. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 62. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 63. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 64. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 65. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 66. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 67. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 68. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 69. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 70. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 71. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 72. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 73. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 74. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 75. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 76. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 77. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 78. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 79. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 80. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 81. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 82. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 83. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 84. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 85. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 86. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 87. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 88. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 89. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 90. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 91. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 92. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 93. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 94. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 95. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object
> Server instance 96. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False
> Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance
> 97. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of Application Object Server instance 98. MSI file:
> ObjectServer64.msi Installed: False Evaluating installation state of
> Application Object Server instance 99. MSI file: ObjectServer64.msi
> Installed: False MSI file: ClientOba64.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> Components64.msi Installed: True MSI file: HelpServer64.msi Installed:
> False MSI file: SetupSupport64.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> TraceParser.msi Installed: False MSI file: MRClient64.msi Installed:
> False MSI file: MRServer64.msi Installed: False MSI file:
> USPayroll64.msi Installed: True MSI file: USPayroll32.msi Installed:
> True MSI file: RapidStartConnectorService.msi Installed: False MSI
> file: RetailHeadquarters64.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> RetailChannelDatabase.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> RetailHardwareStation.msi Installed: False Check if current operating
> system version is Windows 10 or higher. Yes
>
> MSI file: RetailModernPOS.msi Installed: False MSI file:
> RetailScaleOutDeployment.msi Installed: False MSI file: RetailSDK.msi
> Installed: False MSI file: RetailServer.msi Installed: False MSI file:
> RetailPOS.msi Installed: True MSI file: RetailPOSPlugins.msi
> Installed: False MSI file: RetailSaltUtility64.msi Installed: True MSI
> file: CommerceDataExchangeSynchService64.msi Installed: False MSI
> file: RetailDatabaseUtility.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> CommerceDataExchangeReal-timeService.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> CommerceDataExchangeAsyncClient.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> CommerceDataExchangeAsyncServer.msi Installed: True MSI file:
> RetailOnlineChannel.msi Installed: False MSI file:
> CommerceRuntimeSDK.msi Installed: False MSI file: VSTools64.msi
> Installed: False Previously Installed Component: Application Object
> Server (AOS) (01-XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST) Previously Installed Component:
> Client Previously Installed Component: Office add-ins Previously
> Installed Component: Web services on IIS Previously Installed
> Component: .NET Business Connector Previously Installed Component:
> Debugger Previously Installed Component: Reporting Services extensions
>
> AxUtil call is complete. Getting known model databases from AOS
> configuration. Verifying if the model database
> "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on server "SERVER-HOMOLOG" can be updated.
> Using AXUtil to connect to database "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on
> server "SERVER-HOMOLOG". Calling AxUtil to get list of installed
> models. Using AXUtil to connect to database
> "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on server "SERVER-HOMOLOG". AxUtil call is
> complete. Installed models:
>
> ---

> Layer: "Sys", name: "Foundation Upgrade", publisher "Microsoft Corporation", version "6.3.164.0", partition "N/A" Layer:
> "Sys", name: "Foundation", publisher "Microsoft Corporation", version
> "6.3.164.0", partition "N/A" Layer: "Sys", name: "Foundation Labels",
> publisher "Microsoft Corporation", version "6.3.164.0", partition
> "N/A" Layer: "Syp", name: "Hotfix-KB2964763-CL4307967-Foundation",
> publisher "Microsoft Corporation", version "6.3.164.755", partition
> "Foundation"
>
> ->> Listed here all installed KBs .....
>
> Layer: "Syp", name: "Hotfix-KB4552332-4582330-Foundation", publisher
> "Microsoft Corporation", version "6.3.6000.9892", partition
> "Foundation" Layer: "Syp", name:
> "Hotfix-KB4552334-4582327-Foundation", publisher "Microsoft
> Corporation", version "6.3.6000.9887", partition "Foundation" Layer:
> "Syp", name: "Hotfix-KB4552480-4582328-Foundation", publisher
> "Microsoft Corporation", version "6.3.6000.9888", partition "Foundation"

> ---
>
> Found update model(File:
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3-kb4531474-syplabels.axmodel,
> Layer: Syp, Name: SYP Labels, Version: 6.3.6000.9964, Partition:
> SYP-Labels) Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Found update model(File:
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582181.axmodel,
> Layer: Syp, Name: Hotfix-KB4531583-4582181-Foundation, Version:
> 6.3.6000.9517, Partition: Foundation) Found update model(File: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582362.axmodel,
> Layer: Syp, Name: Hotfix-KB4531474-4582362-Foundation, Version:
> 6.3.6000.9964, Partition: Foundation) Evaluating applicability requirements for model file:
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3-kb4531474-syplabels.axmodel
> Required model (Layer: SYS, Name: Foundation, Version: 6.3.164.0) is
> installed: True Update model file is installed: False Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available.
>
> === Checking parameters === Property InstallPath set to: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60' Property InstallPath32Bit set to:
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60'
>
> === Starting UI phase === MSI file: DIXF_Service64.msi Installed: False MSI file: DIXF_AOS64.msi Installed: False MSI file:
> DIXF_Client64.msi Installed: False Msi
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\MSI\VSTools64\VSTools64.msi Found False
> Property ModelDatabaseInstanceName set to:
> 'SERVER-HOMOLOG:XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model' Property
> InstallModelDatabase set to: '1' Property ModelDatabaseInstanceName
> set to: 'SERVER-HOMOLOG:XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model' Property
> InstallModelDatabase set to: '1' Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Model store state cannot be verified.
> Getting schema build version for database XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model on
> server SERVER-HOMOLOG Obtained schema build version string
> "6.3.6000.9100" Getting contents of model file
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3-kb4531474-syplabels.axmodel
> AxUtil call is complete. Getting contents of model file
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582181.axmodel
> AxUtil call is complete. Getting contents of model file
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582362.axmodel
> AxUtil call is complete. Examining customized elements. Using AXUtil
> to connect to database "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on server
> "SERVER-HOMOLOG". Getting contents of model VAR Model AxUtil call is
> complete. Getting contents of model XXX Shared Objects AxUtil call is
> complete. Getting contents of model Common Interface Application
> AxUtil call is complete. Getting contents of model MMT AxUtil call is
> complete. Getting contents of model ToolCommon (Conflict 1) AxUtil
> call is complete. Getting contents of model ToolCommon (Conflict 2)
> AxUtil call is complete. Getting contents of model VAP Model AxUtil
> call is complete. Getting contents of model USR Model AxUtil call is
> complete. Getting contents of model SecurityDevelopmentTool AxUtil
> call is complete. Starting to calculate potential conflicts. Finished
> calculating potential conflicts.
>
> KB4531474: Allocated Charges amounts and FA transactions incorrectly
> posted when we maintain Charges before PO Confirmation – PO line is a
> Procurement category KB4531583: Updated depreciation calculation when
> posting reduction entry with Direct-off type Property AosStart set to:
> '0' Property InstallOtherModelDatabase set to: '1' Property
> InstallModelDatabase set to: '1'
> === Setting up Model Database === Updating model database "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on server "SERVER-HOMOLOG". Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Update model details metadata not available. Update model
> details metadata not available. Update model details metadata not
> available. Following files will be imported as part of this update:
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3-kb4531474-syplabels.axmodel,
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582181.axmodel,
> C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\kb\Models\dynamicsax2012r3_cl4582362.axmodel.
> Using AXUtil to connect to database "XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model" on
> server "SERVER-HOMOLOG". Calling AxUtil to import model file
> "C:\USERS\xxxxxxxx\DOCUMENTS\kb\MODELS\DYNAMICSAX2012R3_CL4582181.AXMODEL".
> AxUtil call is complete. AxUtil call returned errors: You cannot
> import the Foundation (KB4531583) model into a Microsoft layer. Error
> updating model database: Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AxSetupException:
> AxUtil call returned errors:You cannot import the Foundation
> (KB4531583) model into a Microsoft layer.
>
> at Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.Misc.ValidateAxUtilStatus(AxUtilContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.DatabaseSqlModel.DatabaseSqlModelInstanceCommon.ImportModelFiles(IEnumerable`1 filenames, IEnumerable`1 modelsToReplace) at
> Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.DatabaseSqlModel.DatabaseSqlModelInstanceUpdate.Execute()
> An error occurred during setup of Model Database
> (SERVER-HOMOLOG:XXX_AX60_R3_DB_TEST_model). Completed setup of Model
> Database.
>
> === Setup was completed successfully.
>
> === Setup logging ended: 06/05/2020 17:58:37 ErrorLevel/ExitCode: '0' ===

Info:
Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3

---

**Edit 1:**

I'm using axupdate (Application) .exe unzipped from the KB.

I check and the KB is part of the system. See the image below.

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

---

**Edit 2:**

I am trying to install all the latest KBs that were released as of 4/10/2020 by Microsoft.

I have a list for installation. From this list most KBs have the errors mentioned in the log above. However, I was successful in installing the latest 7 KB and 3 Hotifix kernel.

I don't understand how it was possible to install some KBs and others have errors.

Comment: It looks like the KB's are not compatible with your system or you have a bad installer or something. The error is `You cannot import the Foundation (KB4531583) model into a Microsoft layer. Error updating model database: Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AxSetupException: AxUtil call returned errors:You cannot import the Foundation (KB4531583) model into a Microsoft layer.`, which means the KB is attempting to install into the `SYS` or `SYP` layer and is having issues. I'd just guess KB isn't compatible with your system. There are no parameters or anything to set with KB installs to specify a layer.

Comment: To confirm, you are using the GUI to install the KB right? If you are trying to use AXUtil or something to manually install a model, then you need to provide the commands you are running.

Comment: @Alex Kwitny thanks for the comments. I edited the question.Do you think it could be my AX version or my installer version?

Comment: @AlexKwitny The log seems to indicate that the GUI is used to install the hotfix.
@ 8biT If your AX version information is correct, I can see nothing wrong, the installation should work. You may have to contact Microsoft support for this.

Comment: @8biT Just guessing a few things. Before you extracted, did you make sure to `[Right Click>Properties; Unblock]`. Can you try the same update on another AX instance to see if you get the same results?

Comment: @Alex Kwitny Yes, before extracting I made sure about the '[Right Click>Properties; Unblock]'. The same error occurs in other instances of AX

Comment: @8biT navigate to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\ManagementUtilities` (or wherever you installed the AOS component and mgmt utils) and right click on `AXUtilLib.dll`, properties, details tab, and check the version. It should match your current kernel version in AX. Does it?

Comment: @Alex Kwitny Exactly, I checked and the kernel and the dll are the same version. I added a few more details to the question.

Comment: @8biT so your'e using the AXUpdateInstaller (`axupdate.exe`), pointing to your AOS, then just checking all the boxes that are available and you're able to install some but not all? I'd guess it's a bug at this point, with the fact that you're installing the latest fixes being more likely that Microsoft may not be aware of the issue yet.

Comment: We will contact Microsoft, when we have an answer I post here. Thank you.

Comment: See the following question in the Dynamics Community with the same error. Seems Microsoft indeed screwed up some hotfixes. https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/388988/error-when-installing-official-microsoft-hotfix-for-ax2012-r3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ..

I identified that the .axmodel certificate had expired.

[image]

In this case the problem is in the publication of KBs released by Microsoft.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know - in case you don't already - Microsoft are now aware of the situation and are working on rereleasing all `AX 2012 R3` KB's with a new certificate. They expect to have the first ones ready by **Monday 18-05**, is what I was told by a guy from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to install KB 4602212 (2020 1099 fix) released 1/2021.  The AX DEV environment was on 6.3.4000.2085 AX kernel.  I ran into this error trying to install the HF.  It was not an option to apply a newer AX kernel to their DEV environment since SQL server (AX SSRS components) was shared by DEV, TEST & UAT.  The workaround was to copy AXUtillib.dll & AXutilLib.PowerShell.dll from an environment with newer kernel (6.3.6000.9100) from the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\bin or the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\ManagementUtilities folder and replacing these files in the AX DEV environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while installing KB3210144. For what it's worth, for AX R3 I have been directed by MS Support to download the AX Update installer from LCS. Inside your LCS Project (create a dummy project if you don't have any) scroll right to Project Tools / Updates

[image: Project tools]

Where you can download the "Update installer for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3".

[image: Update installer link]

Unfortunately in my case, the tool found I already have the fix installed. [image: Update installer]